# Compare two DataFrames and check for changes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have 2 similar Spark Dataframes `df1` and `df2` that I want to compare for changes:

- `df1` and `df2` share the same columns
- `df2` can have more rows than `df1` but any additional rows in `df2` which is not in `df1` can be ignored when comparing
- Comparaison key columns are `PROGRAM_NAME` and `ACTION`

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
              ["PROG1","ACTION1","10","NEW"],
              ["PROG2","ACTION2","12","NEW"],
              ["PROG3","ACTION1","14","NEW"],
              ["PROG4","ACTION4","16","NEW"]
    ],["PROGRAM_NAME", "ACTION", "VALUE1", "STATUS"])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
          ["PROG1","ACTION1","11","IN PROGRESS"],
          ["PROG2","ACTION2","12","NEW"],
          ["PROG3","ACTION1","20","FINISHED"],
          ["PROG4","ACTION4","14","IN PROGRESS"],
          ["PROG5","ACTION1","20","NEW"]
],["PROGRAM_NAME", "ACTION", "VALUE1", "STATUS"])
```

Showing below in order `df1`, `df2` and the expected result I want after comparing the  2 DataFrames.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked multiple times here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spark%20compare%20two%20dataframes).

Use a simple `join` to get rows that are in `df1` and `df2` and filter on those that have different values for the 2 other columns:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_final = df2.alias("new").join(
        df1.alias("old"),
        (col("new.PROGRAM_NAME") == col("old.PROGRAM_NAME")) & (col("new.ACTION") == col("old.ACTION"))
    ).filter(
        (col("new.VALUE1") != col("old.VALUE1")) | (col("new.STATUS") != col("old.STATUS"))
    ).select("new.*")

df_final.show()

#+------------+-------+------+-----------+
#|PROGRAM_NAME| ACTION|VALUE1|     STATUS|
#+------------+-------+------+-----------+
#|       PROG3|ACTION1|    20|   FINISHED|
#|       PROG4|ACTION4|    14|IN PROGRESS|
#|       PROG1|ACTION1|    11|IN PROGRESS|
#+------------+-------+------+-----------+
```

You can also add the filter condition directly to the join condition

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution in Spark:

```
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('PROG1', 'ACTION1', 10, 'NEW'),
        ('PROG2', 'ACTION2', 12, 'NEW'),
        ('PROG3', 'ACTION1', 14, 'NEW'),
        ('PROG4', 'ACTION4', 16, 'NEW'),
    ],
    ['PROGRAM_NAME', 'ACTION', 'Value1', 'Status']
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ('PROG1', 'ACTION1', 11, 'IN PROGRESS'),
        ('PROG2', 'ACTION2', 12, 'NEW'),
        ('PROG3', 'ACTION1', 20, 'FINISHED'),
        ('PROG4', 'ACTION4', 14, 'IN PROGRESS'),
        ('PROG5', 'ACTION1', 20, 'NEW'),
    ],
    ['PROGRAM_NAME', 'ACTION', 'Value1', 'Status']
)

df1 = df1.alias('df1')
df2 = df2.alias('df2')
df = df1.join(df2, on=['PROGRAM_NAME', 'ACTION'], how='inner')
df = df.filter(F.col('df1.Status') != F.col('df2.Status'))
df.select(
  F.col('PROGRAM_NAME'),
  F.col('ACTION'),
  *[F.col(f'df2.{col}') for col in df2.columns[2:]]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.This almost worked . But If i add a new row to DF1 and DF2 where values in all columns are same(no change). It should "not" show up in final dataframe because no data is changed . If possible could you send reply in Spark format

Comment: @Avi, solution is now written in Spark and with that fix

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result like this:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {"PROGRAM_NAME":["PROG1","PROG2","PROG3","PROG4"],
         "ACTION":["ACTION1","ACTION2","ACTION1","ACTION4"],
         "Value1":[10,12,14,16],
         "Status":["NEW","NEW","NEW","NEW"]} 
dict2 = {"PROGRAM_NAME":["PROG1","PROG2","PROG3","PROG4","PROG5"],
         "ACTION":["ACTION1","ACTION2","ACTION1","ACTION4","ACTION1"],
         "Value1":[11,12,20,14,20],
         "Status":["IN PROGRES","NEW","FINISHED","IN PROGRES","NEW"]}

DF1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

DF3 = DF2.copy()
DF3 = DF3[DF3["PROGRAM_NAME"].isin(DF1["PROGRAM_NAME"])]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: why didn't you need the action criteria as determined in the problem

Comment: Thanks for reply.This almost worked . But If i add a new row to DF1 and DF2 where values in all columns are same(no change). It should "not" show up in final dataframe because no data is changed .  If possible could you send reply in Spark format

Answer (score 0):

You can merge df1 and df2 and retain `VALUE1` and `STATUS` just of df2

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

Keeping suffixes of columns of df1 as `_x` and that of df2 as blank and then retaining just the columns of `df2`

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['PROGRAM_NAME', 'ACTION'], suffixes=('_x', ''))[df2.columns]
```

[image]